# Is there any way to test if a Players inventory is not full in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is there any way to test if a player's inventory is not full (eg. atleast 1 empty slot anywhere in the inventory, not counting Armor Slots) with command blocks and whatnot?

Comment: I think it would be possible by checking each individual slot with command blocks and using lots of comparators + AND gates, but that would take forever.

Comment: Well, good to know that it might atleast be possible. Any clue how I would check the slots themselves (ie. what command I would need for each command block?)

Comment: If you solved your own question, please post it as an answer rather than editing the question.

Answer (score 2):

I found /testfor @p {Inventory:[{Slot:0b}]}, which outputs a 1 block signal if there's an item there, and no signal if that slot is empty. This would require 36 command blocks, to check every slot (including the hotbar; 27 to just check the inventory, 40 if you wanted to check armor slots)

Comment: Major flaw with straight up using test for: NOT multiplayer friendly. Also this is very labourous to do.

Comment: Looks like you can also check all slots in one single command, since as you see, the `Inventory` tag accepts an array. I'd assume you can stuff all slots into that array. Not sure if that checks for non-empty or full, though.

Answer (score 2):

This solution works for 1.14 for sure, I have not tested for 1.13. It can be elaborated on to check the entire inventory in one command; however, in this example I am only checking the hotbar.

```
/execute if entity @p[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:0b},{Slot:1b},{Slot:2b},{Slot:3b},{Slot:4b},{Slot:5b},{Slot:6b},{Slot:7b},{Slot:8b}]}] run say Hotbar is not full.
```